# How to train YOLOv5 model with weights found in previous experiment?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, yolo, yolov5

I was training a YOLOv5 model. I trained it for 50 epochs. But I think mAP still can increase. How can I use the weights (best.pt) attained from the 50 epoch experiment to run the new experiment of 60 epochs? I am using this code. How do I set the weights?

```
 !python train.py --batch 27 --epochs 60  --data /content/yolov5/data.yaml --weights yolov5x.pt
```

The 50 epoch best.pt file is gained running model on YOLOv5l. Now I am running it on YOLOv5x. Would it be useful?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the weight parameter with the location of your best.pt weight
!python train.py --batch 27 --epochs 60  --data /content/yolov5/data.yaml --weights //location of the best.pt//